# Greedy Algorithm - Exchange Argument

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, computer-science

Consider the following problem :

**Input:** $2n$ positive integers (repetitions allowed) $l_1,l_2, ..., l_{2n}$.

**Output:** $n$ pairs $(l_{11}, l_{12}), (l_{21}, l_{22}), ..., (l_{n1}, l_{n2})$ such that $\sum_{j=1}^{n} l_{j1}\cdot l_{j2}$ is maximal.

My solution is to pick the 2 largest integers from the input on each greedy iteration, and it will provide the maximal sum ($\sum_{j=1}^{n} l_{j1}\cdot l_{j2}$).

I'm trying to proof the correctness of the algorithm using exchange argument by induction, but I'm not sure how to formally prove that after swapping an element between my solution and the optimal solution, I have a solution which is not worse than before.

I'll appreciate any direction.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to see that your solution is maximal (though not necessarily maximum, for that see the comments on this answer):

Let $a\geq b\geq c\geq d$.

Then we have that
$$(ab+cd)-(ac+bd)=a(b-c)+d(c-b)=(a-d)(b-c)\geq 0$$ with equality iff $b=c$ or $a=d$. However, in either case the "swap" only exchanges equal numbers. Similarly, we have that $$(ab+cd)-(ad+bc)=a(b-d)+c(d-b)=(a-c)(b-d)\geq 0$$ with equality iff $a=c$ or $b=d$. However, in either case the "swap" only exchanges equal numbers.

Comment: Doesn't this only take care of pairings that have a "Hamming distance" of $2$?  In other words, suppose the greedy algorithm has thus far paired $a$ and $b$, and $c$ and $d$.  Now we see integers $e$ and $f$.  What if the optimal pairing was $a$ and $f$, $b$ and $c$, and $d$ and $e$?

Comment: @BrianTung Yes it does, but that's how I understand "maximal" in this context. I'm not claiming (and the OP isn't asking) that this is the maximum. But it is maximal.

Comment: It comes from the "rearangment inequality" (don't know if you say it like this in english) : if $x_1,\dots,x_n$ and $y_1,\dots,y_n$ are two strictly positive sequences, then $$\sum x_iy_i \le \sum x_{\sigma(i)}y_{\psi(i)}$$, where $(x_{\sigma(i)})_i$ and $(y_{\sigma(i)})_i$ are the ordered sequences extracted from $(x_i)$ and $(y_i)$. It can be proved by induction.

Comment: @NicolasFRANCOIS I think your inequality is the wrong way around.

Comment: @adfriedman : are you sure ? $2\times 3+5\times 1=11<17=1\times 2+3\times 5$, so to maximize the sum of products, you have to put the two sequences in the same order...

Comment: I think the right name is "reordering inequality" :-)

Comment: @NicolasFRANCOIS You state that $x_1,\dotsc, x_n$ etc are strictly increasing and then you started talking about extracted ordered sequences. 
The Rearrangement Inequality, as given on wikipedia, states that for non-decreasing $\{x_k\}$ and $\{y_k\}$, for every permutation $\sigma$,
$$ \sum_{k=1}^n x_{n-k} y_k \leq \sum_{k=1}^n x_{\sigma(k)}y_k \leq \sum_{k=1}^n x_iy_i$$

Comment: @adfriedman : I said $(x_i)$ and $(y_i)$ are positive sequences, not that they were ordered...

Comment: @adfriedman : I think we both agree on the result. Maybe my statement was not clear. I'm not fluent enough in math english :-(

Comment: @NicolasFRANCOIS The distinction is superfluous either way: it holds for all reals. I can only read French mathematics, I couldn't imagine trying to communicate in it. Good luck!

Comment: @adfriedman :  Agreed

Comment: @StellaBiderman: I'd say, given that OP wants "*the* maximal sum" (emphasis mine), it's at least plausible that they want the maximum.

Comment: @BrianTung I've amended my answer to be clearer.